# Raspberry Pi 3 Detect Microphone in Volume c#

Tags: c#, audio, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I am working on a c# project on Microsoft IoT Core where I need to detect something like:

```
if(micInVolume >= setVolume)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

This would need to be real-time on the Raspberry Pi 3 with an external USB sound card and just a microphone. I have looked into NAudio a little bit but I don't think it will work or it might just be that I didn't do it right and didn't have the proper references. I was looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8536025/9476675) but wasn't able to get that to work, and I think  that may be because I just don't understand it well.

Comment: For UWP, you can check [Sound Volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/sound#sound-volume-override) to see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't think that I worded it correctly. What I meant to say was let's say someone started talking next to the microphone and the input from that was above a certain level. I'm not sure if sound volume can do that, but if it can I would appreciate it if you were to elaborate.

Comment: I am consulting with the related engineer and will inform you ASAP.